# Sub Query issue in PHP MVC CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

```
select * from tblprojects where projectID in 
              (Select ProjectID from tblprojectBackups where Userid = 2 and StatusID = 3)
```

I have above query. I am using below code in PHP MVC CI.

```
$query = $this->_ci->db->select('*')->from('tblproject');
$this->_ci->db->where('`projectid` IN (SELECT `projectid` FROM `tblprojectBackups` 
               where `StatusID`=3 and `UserID`=2)', NULL, FALSE);
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
}
```

This is not working and giving error. Am I missing something in code ?

Comment: If CI 3 in case, you can use `get_compiled_select()`.

Answer (score -1):

You can direct pass `sql query` in `query` method in codeigniter.

Like this -

```
 $sql="select * from tblprojects where projectID in 
          (Select ProjectID from tblprojectBackups where Userid = 2 and StatusID = 3)";


$query=$this->db->query($sql);

return $query->result(); #return object
```